# How do you use Dependency Injection with EF to resolve a DbSet with an interfaced generic type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement a DbSet in Entity Framework (EF) 7 that is based on an interface that gets injected at run-time, and I am not sure how to do this.  For example:

```
internal class DataContext : DbContext
{
    internal DbSet<IUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When I query this from my app, I want IUser to be resolved to my domain "User" object and returned.  When I try to do this, I get an error that says:

> "The entity type 'value' provided for the argument 'IUser' must be a reference type" at the Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.ValidEntityType(Type value, String parameterName).

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.  I have read answers to other related questions that basically indicate that you should not abstract your entities, and while this may be true, I am just trying to figure out if there is a way to accomplish this with EF.

Comment: Why do you use interface for entities (DTO?)? Do your entities contains any business logic?

Comment: I understand it may not make sense to interface my entities.  I still want to understand if it is possible to use an interface for your DbSet type and have the concrete type resolve at runtime with EF.

Comment: To clarify, we basically are trying to make it so that our DTO's are not just DTO's, but instead have our repositories return true domain objects.  We have done this in the past using the Onion pattern and EF (which worked great), but we want to be able to dependency inject our domain objects in case we have a multi tenant variation that requires injection of different domain logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible with EF7, but is a highly requested feature in the user voice for EF7 (and in fact they have indicated in their issues list that it will be added, but just not in time for RTM).

[UserVoice](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1272291-support-interfaces-as-entity-and-complex-types)

[Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1489)